# How to join two tables with date and week number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, cross-join

How do i connect both these tables to have data connected based on department names and week number. So that if the weeknumber don't match up, it shows nulls for others.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3bbd3/1

Answer (score 1):

A full outer join should do the trick:

```
SELECT          d.id, 
                d.name, 
                f.id, 
                DATEPART(WEEK, setupdate) as WeekNumber  
FROM            departments d
FULL OUTER JOIN forecast f ON d.name = f.name AND
                DATEPART(WEEK, setupdate) = DATEPART(WEEK, forecast)
```

Comment: I didn't full understand the question. But dont you need join by Id or Name too?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza you're right, good catch. I somehow skipped that requirement when reading the question. I've edited my answer accordingly.